# How django "Timefield" can be timezone aware without date?

Tags: python, django

I want to make these fields timezone aware without date,

```
default_start_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
default_end_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

so this value will show to the user based on activated timezone

Comment: This is quite "nonsensical" I think, since for example a lot of timezones have daylight saving time, and thus the time depends on the date itself. 12:00 UTC is not always 13:00 CET, unfortunately it is not.

Comment: In addition, 03:00 in Paris is something like 23:00 in New York, but in the previous day. It doesn't make much sense to have a timezone-aware time-only field.